# Typescript toUpperCase() conversion is not accepted

Tags: typescript

I have source type defined as:

```
unit: 'hour'|'day'|'week'|'month'
```

I am using it as lowercase for moment.js library. Bu I also need it uppercase for backend endpoint. So my http method accepts parameter as

```
unit: 'HOUR'|'DAY'|'WEEK'|'MONTH'
```

But the typescript does not accept conversion via toUpperCase in method call.

> Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'HOUR'|'DAY'|'WEEK'|'MONTH'

[image]

Is there an elegant solution in typescript that I will not destroy static type checking and in the same time I will not make extra convertor helper function (custom toUpperCase)?

Thanks for advices! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can extend the declaration of `toUpperCase` to have an extra overload that takes this specific union of string literal types and returns the upper case version of the union type. There is no extra function, just an extra compile time declaration:

```
interface String {
    toUpperCase(this: 'hour'|'day'|'week'|'month') : 'HOUR'|'DAY'|'WEEK'|'MONTH'
}

declare let low: 'hour'|'day'|'week'|'month';
let up = low.toUpperCase(); // typed as "HOUR" | "DAY" | "WEEK" | "MONTH"
```

**Note**

If you are in a module you will need to redeclare string in the global namespace:

```
declare global {
    interface String {
        toUpperCase(this: 'hour' | 'day' | 'week' | 'month'): 'HOUR' | 'DAY' | 'WEEK' | 'MONTH'
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not 100% sure how this works, but it works, thanks :) I was expecting that this breaks something else, like another use of toUpperCase(). But I did not found the case. Excellent!

Comment: @Luckylooke The compiler will pick the new overload only if the current `this` is the union type, so it should not break anything else. I'm 99.99% sure this will only have the intended effect, if you find any issues let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Depend on previous answer you can make the extend of declaration more generic with [TypeScript predefine](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html#uppercasestringtype)

```
interface String {
  toUpperCase<T extends string>(this: T): Uppercase<T>;
}
```